# How to set up external merge tool?

Tags: plasticscm

Is it possible to configure plastic client to work with a mergetool without GUI (non interactive way)? I have an installation on Jenkins server (Ubuntu 16) to do continuous integration with plastic scm.

The issue is the pipeline should be able to resolve some merge conflicts: 
e.g. "one file modified by two contributors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mergetool bundled with Plastic has the following parameters (mergetool --help):

> -a|--automatic:

Tries to resolve the merge automatically.

> --silent:

If the merge can't be resolved automatically (requires the user interaction), the merge tool is shown. This option must be used combined with the --automatic option. When a merge can't be resolved automatically, this option causes the tool to return immediately with a non-zero exit code (no merge tool is shown).
If the tool was able to solve the merge automatically, the program returns exit code 0.

NOTE: You can also configure with Plastic any other custom external merge tool.

Comment: I installed plastic client on jenkins server like this: `apt-get install -y plasticscm-client-core`. By default, there is no executable `mergetool`

Comment: Please, in Linux it is called "gtkmergetool".

Comment: Sorry, my jenkins server has no garphical user interface. `jenkins@0f9230409dda:~/workspace/dummy-api-develop$ gtkmergetool -a

(gtkmergetool:169): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: `

Comment: In the "/home/xxx/.plastic/client.conf" file you can customize the parameters to be used when Plastic runs "gtkmergetool". If issue persists, please reach us at support@codicesoftware.com